# Customizing google form post action

Tags: html, google-forms

I'm using a google form in my contact section of the site. I managed to customized and configure all my `div` elements with the response ids from google form so I receive any contact details. The issue I have is that when I click "Submit" the user is taken to the "Thank you for your response" default's view of google form. What can I do so that instead of receiving the "Thank you" default style from google, I take the user to my own "thank you" page or just pop a modal with thank you? I don't wan't the google form default thank you message.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a hyperlink to that submit button. Ex- `<button href="thankyou.html">`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp see more about href attribute